# Why EKWeekday fails to return nil when initialising with incorrect value

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekeventkit

I have notice that `EKWeekday` can be initialised with incorrect value, and it is not returning nil.

```
let weekDayInt = 10
guard let weekDay = EKWeekday(rawValue: weekDayInt)  else { return }
let recurrence =  EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(weekDay)
```

when initialising the `EKWeekday` with incorect value it not return nil but when I try to use that value to create a new `EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek` it crashes with `Invalid day number`

is there any other way to validate the correctness of value besides validating weekDayInt <= 7 && weekDayInt >=1

Comment: Looks like the default init?(rawValue:) has been overridden and is misbehaving. I believe you have to handle this yourself, perhaps with your own custom init.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yah, a custom init was my approach also, Thanks